# How to concatenate String Tensors with tensorflow.js?

Tags: javascript, tensorflow

I try to concatenate two tensors using tensorflow.js. If both tensors only contain numeric values it works fine.

```js
var a = tf.tensor2d([[1.0, 2.0, 3.0], [10.0, 20.0, 30.0]]);
var b = tf.tensor2d([[8.0, 7.0, 5.0], [3.0, 11.0, 23.0]]);
var a_concat_b = a.concat(b, 1);
a_concat_b.print();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tensorflow/0.14.2/tf.min.js"></script>
```

But if a tensor contains strings it fails.

```js
var c = tf.tensor2d([["1.0", "2.0", "3.0"], ["10.0", "20.0", "30.0"]]);
var d = tf.tensor2d([["8.0", "7.0", "5.0"], ["3.0", "11.0", "23.0"]]);
var c_concat_d = c.concat(d, 1);
c_concat_d.print();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tensorflow/0.14.2/tf.min.js"></script>
```

Error message:

> Uncaught Error: Argument 'tensors[0]' passed to 'concat' must be numeric tensor, but got string tensor

Is it not possible at all to concatenate tensors containing strings or how could this be achieved?

The [tensorflow.js API documentation](https://js.tensorflow.org/api/latest/#concat) only says that the types must match:

> #### `tf.concat (tensors, axis?)`
>
> Concatenates a list of `tf.Tensors` along a given axis.
>
> The tensors ranks and types must match, and their sizes must match in all dimensions except `axis`.

Thanks in advance and best regards.

Comment: It seems like `concat()` only supports numeric tensors.

Comment: I wonder why you are using tensorflow for string array concatenation. tensorflow is not meant to be used with string data type, at least not the way you're using it.

Comment: At the end I want to concatenate a tensor containing string value with a tensor containing only numeric values. the second tensor is the one hot representation of one of the elements in the first tensor.

Answer (score 0):

Note: I'm not at all familiar with tensors or the package you are using, so I have no idea if there is a way to do what you want with strings.

Despite that I think I have a fix (assuming you are actually working with arrays of numbers that are saved a strings).

First change the array of strings into an array of floats using the parseFloat method

```
var array1 = ['1.0', '2.0', '3.0'],
    array2 = ['10.0', '20.0', '30.0'],
    array3 = ['8.0', '7.0', '5.0'],
    array4 = ['3.0', '11.0', '23.0'],
    newArray1 = [],
    newArray2 = [],
    newArray3 = [],
    newArray4 = [];

for (var i=0; i<array1.length; i++) {
newArray1[i] = parseFloat(array1[i]);       
newArray2[i] = parseFloat(array2[i]);
newArray3[i] = parseFloat(array3[i]);
newArray4[i] = parseFloat(array4[i]);
}
//This is assuming the arrays are always the same length. 
//If they aren't, then you will have to make a separate for loop for each array.
```

Now running your code should work:

```
var c = tf.tensor2d([newArray1, newArray2]);
var d = tf.tensor2d([newArray3, newArray4]);
var c_concat_d = c.concat(d, 1);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but in my case I want to concatenate a string tensor and a numeric tensor. Both tensor are having the same ranks.

Comment: Sorry, in that case I can't really help.  I don't even know what a tensor is :)

Answer (score 0):

Old Question but you can convert each Tensor to an array and create a new tensor.

```js
var c = tf.tensor2d([
  ["1.0", "2.0", "3.0"],
  ["10.0", "20.0", "30.0"]
]);
var d = tf.tensor2d([
  ["8.0", "7.0", "5.0"],
  ["3.0", "11.0", "23.0"]
]);

var c_concat_d = tf.tensor([c.arraySync(), d.arraySync()])
c_concat_d.print();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tensorflow/tfjs@2.0.0/dist/tf.min.js"></script>
```

**Note: This uses a more recent version of tensorflowjs than is used by the OP.**